# Node.js Problem redirecting routine post method

Tags: node.js, express, post

I write here for who can help me, since I'm new to NodeJS, I'm trying to do something simple, but in the end it doesn't work for me.

I want from the frontend, to make a request to the backend, through the ajax post method. When executing it, from the frontend send a JSON object to the backend and then from the backend it must redirect to another page to the frontend (the latter is what I could not achieve)

Example of what I try

**Frontend**

```
     var objAgente = {
          "FIRSTNAME": "PEDRO",
          "LASTNAME": "PEREZ",
          "NRORUT": "123456789",
          "NROAGENT": "3",
          "HRCONNECT": "12:12:12"
     };

     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/LoginAgente',
          data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData": objAgente}),
          success: function(data) {console.log('todo OK')},
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: 'json'
     });
```

**Backend**

```
     const express = require("express");
     const router = express.Router();

     router.use(express.json())
     router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

     router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
          res.render('loading.html', { title: 'Iniciando Sistema'});
     });

     router.get('/Inicio', (req,res)=>{
          res.render('confInitial.html', { title: 'Inicio de Sistema'});
     });

     router.get('/Agente', (req,res)=>{
          res.render('PanelAgente/Agente.html', { title: 'Equipo solo Agente'});
     });

     router.post('/LoginAgente', function (req, res) {
          var newUser = req.body;
          console.log(newUser);
          res.redirect('/Agente');
     });

     module.exports = router;
```

When I execute the sending of the JSON object to the backend, the data arrives since I can print it by console, but the res.redirect is not fulfilled;

It does not return an error, but it does not redirect me to where I want.

Thank you very much to those who can give me an idea of ​​what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are sending request using AJAX ,  server can not redirect to other page in AJAX request , you have to redirect user after you getting response from AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/LoginAgente',
      data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData": objAgente}),
      success: function(data, textStatus, request){

         // add redirect link here 
         window.location.href = '/add_link_to_redirect_here';

      },
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately question author using SO mentors to achieve his goals without doing anything himself

Comment: @num8er
If I were an expert, maybe I would be more helping or clarifying how [Saurabh Mistry] did it in such a simple way, that it slandered people.

Similarly, thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @MiguelEduardoRangelGomez really please take Your time and watch these: https://youtu.be/L72fhGm1tfE  https://youtu.be/wI1CWzNtE-M https://youtu.be/eR3rcalj06Q

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`res.redirect('/Agente');`

Try

`res.send({redirect: '/Agente'});`

UPDATE:

Frontend

```
 var objAgente = {
      "FIRSTNAME": "PEDRO",
      "LASTNAME": "PEREZ",
      "NRORUT": "123456789",
      "NROAGENT": "3",
      "HRCONNECT": "12:12:12"
 };

 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/LoginAgente',
      data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData": objAgente}),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data && data.redirect) {
          window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
      },
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David R

I placed as you indicated, but nothing happened.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @MiguelEduardoRangelGomez also need to change frontend code:  window.location.href = data.redirect

Answer (score 0):

No need to change backend code, since it may be useful in future when will need non-ajax authentication.

So simply try to get `Location` header from response and redirect using `window.location.href`

**FRONTEND**

```js
var objAgente = {
      "FIRSTNAME": "PEDRO",
      "LASTNAME": "PEREZ",
      "NRORUT": "123456789",
      "NROAGENT": "3",
      "HRCONNECT": "12:12:12"
 };

 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/LoginAgente',
      data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData": objAgente}),
      success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        const redirectTo = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
        if (redirectTo) {
          window.location.href = redirectTo;
        }
      },
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
 });
```

Comment: hello num8er,

I happen to want to redirect from here. 

router.post('/LoginAgente', function (req, res) {
          //some actions and queries to BD and then
          res.redirect('/Agente');
 });

Since, within the post method I will execute some queries and end up putting together a JSON to return it to the page that I will redirect

Comment: @MiguelEduardoRangelGomez You cannot respond both with redirect and json body. it’s incorrect. if You want to respond json so see answer from David and do it.

Comment: I am very grateful for the interest in helping me.

The way to redirect that you indicate to me is correct and it works, but in addition to redirecting ...

I needed to pass certain variables other than URL.

I wanted to send these variables from the backend through the EJS template engine.

How else can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you're trying to use and see entire body

```
var newUser = req.body;
console.log(newUser);
```

you should in your front pass the object like:

```
data: JSON.stringify(objAgente)
```

and do what you're doing:

```
req.body
```

cause if you're passing you're object into a new object he'll understand that you're gonna access these proprieties inside the obj, like:

```
req.body.objectData.FIRSTNAME
```